# Drawing Pacman's Face in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pacman

So I'm coding Pacman in Python just for fun and I want to create pacman's open face (when he is eating food) using Tkinter graphics. How exactly do I draw an open face? I was thinking about using canvas.create_arc to create the open mouth but it doesn't work properly :(

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: More importantly, how do you draw the bow for Mrs. Pacman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you would use the `create_arc` method. Set the start to `45` and the `extent` to `270` and it will look like pacman is facing to the right with his mouth open.

Since you are just learning I'll not post the exact code so you'll have a chance to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
import sys
if sys.hexversion > 0x02ffffff:
    from tkinter import *
else:
    from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    #Creates an arc     
    def draw_pieslice(self, canv,x,y,rad):
        return canv.create_arc(x-rad, y-rad, x+rad, y+rad, fill='yellow', style=PIESLICE, start=self.start_angle, extent=self.stop_angle)

    #To toggle the start and extent values of the arc, such that the pacman opens and closes the mouth
    #Initially the mouth will be completely closed, but as the value is toggled we will get a 45deg space (mouth opens)
    def toggle_mouth(self):
        if self.start_angle is 1:   
            self.start_angle = 45
            self.stop_angle  = 270
        else:                       
            self.start_angle = 1
            self.stop_angle  = 359

    #moves the pacman body horizontally
    def movecircle(self):
        self.repeat = self.repeat - 1           #sets a limit to horizontal movement
        self.canvas.move(self.PacMouth,1,0)     
        if (self.repeat % 10) is 0:             #Adjusting the value in here, will help to adjust the mouth movement speed with the horizontal body movement
            self.toggle_mouth()
            self.canvas.itemconfig(self.PacMouth, start = self.start_angle, extent = self.stop_angle)
        if self.repeat is not 0:
            self.after(10, self.movecircle)     #By adjusting the time, we can adjust the horizontal movement speed

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.start_angle = 1
        self.stop_angle  = 359

        self.canvas = Canvas(width=800, height=480, bg='black')
        self.canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        text = self.canvas.create_text(50,10, text="Pacman! Yeah!", fill="white")
        self.PacMouth = self.draw_pieslice(self.canvas,100,240,20)
        self.repeat = 600

        self.movecircle()


root = Tk()
root.config(bg = "black")
root.title("Im on stack overflow")
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(800, 480))
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```